# Adding images to a folder. Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am writing a small project on django with an app 'santechnic' and ran into a problem.to In which folder should I upload the images in the model Product so that the get request can find them?

> santechnic/models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
category_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="", primary_key=True)
category_image = models.ImageField(default="", upload_to='upload/images/categories')


class Product(models.Model):
product_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
length = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
width = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
height = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
product_image = models.ImageField(default="", upload_to=)
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

> urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('santechnic/', include('santechnic.urls'))
]
```

> santechnic/urls.py

```
app_name = "santechnic"
urlpatterns = \[
path('', views.CategoryView.as_view(), name='category'),
path('\<slug:category_name\>/', views.ProductsView.as_view(), name='products'),
path('\<slug:category_name\>/\<slug:product_name\>/', views.ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
\]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

> santechnic/views.py

```
class CategoryView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'santechnic/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'category_list'
    model = Category


class ProductsView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'santechnic/products.html'
    context_object_name = 'products_list'
    model = Product
```

> part of settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = ''
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
```

> Directory

[image]

I've tried generate path:

```
def generate_path(instance, filename):
    return '%s/upload/images/products/' % instance.category.category_name
```

But I had exception SuspiciousFileOperation.

Also for example I manually add path 'toilets/upload/images/products' in upload_to
and got  "GET /santechnic/toilets/toilets/upload/images/products/1.png HTTP/1.1" 404
(here category_name='toilets').

If path is 'upload/images/products' I again get "GET /santechnic/toilets/upload/images/products/1.png HTTP/1.1" 404

Help me, please. How can I solve it?

Comment: your `generate_path` looses `filename`. here is a [correct example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to). Both MEDIA_ROOT, MEDIA_URL are empty which is totally incorrect, please use search on SO and take a look at the docs.

Comment: Can you answer on my question? Can I have one MEDIA_URL for images which are displayed on different urls?

Comment: Yes. MEDIA_URL is a common prefix for all media files. The rest of a file URL can be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to create folder manually for to store images, when you write upload_to in model field, it will create media folder automatically inside your project.

In models.py:

```
product_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/") #after writing this, it will create media/images folder inside your project.
```

To display this on template:

```
<img src="/media/{{product_image}}" /> #here image will display.
```

**Settings.py:**

```
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

Comment: I've added `MEDIA_URL = 'media/'; MEDIA_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')` and `upload_to='images\'` in both models. I've tried your html-code `<img src="media/{{ category.category_image }}"/>` on the page `http://127.0.0.1:8000/santechnic/` and it works, but it doesn't work with code  `<img src="media/{{ product.product_image }}"/>` on the page `http://127.0.0.1:8000/santechnic/toilets/` the urlpattern of which is `<slug:category_name>/`. I suppose I should change `MEDIA_URL` for every category, but `MEDIA_URL` is permanent. Or I should change something else?

Comment: Don't add backward slash(\) in upload_to. use only forward slash(/) in upload_to="images/"

Comment: And in img tag, change this <img src="media/{{ category.category_image }}"/> to this <img src="/media/{{ category.category_image }}"/> Here added forward slash to the begining of media

Comment: Thank you, the solving of the problem are settting media_root and media_url and adding it in urls.py in the project (not in the app). In html I use the url attribute of the image.

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: Yes, it is working now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Pillow?

```
pip install pillow
```

maybe you should Google this and try.

Comment: Pillow is installed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).